# xcodebuild test on Xcode 14: Could not find test host for DoSomethingElseTests: TEST_HOST evaluates

Tags: xcodebuild, xcode-build-settings, xcode14, xcodebuilder

I'm running the following command to build and test my project:

```
xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration DoSomethingElse -project DoSomethingElse.xcodeproj -scheme DoSomethingElse -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 8 Plus" test
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Reason: Could not find test host for DoSomethingElseTests: TEST_HOST evaluates
```

[image]

But I run the unit test using XCode IDE works just fine.

[image]

Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong?, or if there is a way around this?

I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Are you sure your configuration is called `DoSomethingElse` in `-configuration DoSomethingElse`? Usually they are named as `Debug` or `Release`. It's totally possible you may have created a custom configuration named `DoSomethingElse`. But based on that error, xcodebuild cannot find a binary to test, likely cause the binary doesn't exist, likely cause it never gets created. Try running the `xcodebuild` command without `test` to confirm it actually is able to build a binary.